# Query table A from table B by getting the comma separated values from a column using the user id supplied MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I have tried left join, inner join, join and nested select queries but it is always giving me one result set even though table A has multiple comma separated values.

The simplest solution which i could figure was query twice which gives me the result, if i query the product_ids from table A and then based on the result query table B. Where product_ids has multiple comma separated values.

How could i make a single query like this one?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sys_products` 
WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT sys_cart.product_ids 
    FROM `sys_cart` 
    WHERE userid = 2 
)
```

Why won't this query work? The FIND_IN_SET also does not work.

Comment: @Barmar if it would have been correct the user would have accepted it. You can't mark questions duplicate only if you have answered them would have appreciated the help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try that solution? Doesn't it work? You should really normalize your data, though.

Comment: @Barmar it does not work. The case is entirely something else i do not wish to concat any of the data i just wish to display the list of the products which are saved as comma separated strings in another table.

Comment: So i figured the solution which is not given by @Barmar in his solution.  The query is something like this  SELECT * FROM sys_products INNER JOIN sys_cart ON FIND_IN_SET(sys_products.id, sys_cart.product_ids)  WHERE sys_cart.userid=2.

Comment: Isn't that the same as my answer in the linked question? The relevant part is using `ON FIND_IN_SET(...)`

Comment: Here's a simpler duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672 I'll use this one in the future for questions like this.