# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT LIKE Follow Sequence

Tags: mysql

I have 3 Tables:
The first Contains Products:

```
+-----+-------------+---------------+
|  ID |     NAME    | IngredientsID |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| 01  |   Pizza     | 01,02,04      |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| 02  |   Spagetti  | 01,02         |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| 03  | Cheesburger | 01,04,02,03   |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| 04  |   Nuggets   | 01,04         |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
```

The second contains Ingredients Details:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  ID |     NAME    |  Allergens  | Frozen |
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 01  |   Flour     |   01        |    0   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 02  |   Water     |             |    0   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 03  |   Nuts      |  03         |    0   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 04  |   Fish      |  02         |    1   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

The second contains Allergens details:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+
|  ID |     NAME    |  Allergens  |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 01  |   Flour     |   01        |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 02  |   Water     |             |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 03  |   Nuts      |  03         |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 04  |   Fish      |  02         |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

now with a query I need to extract for a given `Food_ID`, the list of Ingredients' Names and Allergenes Names:

and I used the following query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    (
        select 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Name SEPARATOR ',')
        from Ingredients
        where (select IngredientsID from Products where ID=@Food_ID) 
        like concat('%',IngredientID,'%')
    ) IngredientsNames
FROM products 
WHERE ID=@Food_ID

(for allergenes Names I used a nested GROUP_CONCAT)
```

that return for `@Food_ID=03` something like:

```
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
| ID  |  Name       | IngredientsNames           |
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
| 03  | Cheesburger | Water,Flour,Fish,Nuts      |
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
```

I'm new with MYSQL, and I tried to use `IN` and also `FIND_IN_SET` operator but did not succeed: so I used `LIKE`:
I think there is a better way to obtain the result, but it works although not perfectly:

in fact, Ingredients has to be indicated according to their quantity in the Dish:
First the most present and so on, while the list of Ingredients give by the query contains ingredients name in random order, 
while it should follow the order stated in `IngredientsID` in `Products` Table:
therefore

```
Flour,Fish,Water,Nuts
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` is the correct way to join the tables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672

Comment: You can put `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` call to specify the ordering. But I don't see where you have quantity.

Comment: You should stop using comma-separated lists and normalize your schema.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're definitively right.. but this is what I have inherited: clearly could convert it but I was trying to find a solution with the actual tables

Comment: @Barmar Actually there are no quantity: `ORDER BY` should be by the sequence of the `IngredientsID` value that in the example is `01,04,02,03`  therefore the result should be `Flour,Fish,Water,Nuts`

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 you can use `REGEXP_INSTR()` to find the position of the ingredient ID in the comma-separated list, and order by that. If not, you'll need to write a stored function that finds the position, there's nothing built-in.

Comment: Thanks alot for the hints.. unfortunately it is installed MySQL 5.7... therefore I will try to build a function counting the number of the commas...