# Count rows nin a column from one table do not appear in another table

Tags: mysql

I have TableA with 5 rows in column `siteID` ( so 5 different sites).

I have TableB that stores userIDs and which sites they have access to. I need to take all 5 siteIDs from TableA and check to see if any of the siteIDs are NOT in TableB for a specific user.

I'm trying something similar to this pseudocode but not sure how the syntax should go:

```
   SET @invalidSites = (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM userSiteAccess AS usa
            RIGHT JOIN customer.sitesVsUsers AS cust
                ON usa.listOfSites = cust.siteID
            WHERE cust.siteID IS NULL);
```

EXAMPLE:

```
TABLE A
listOfSites
 1
 2
 3

TableB
userID   siteAccess
50       3
```

The count should return 2 as the list of sites has 2 additional rows  (site 1 and site 2) but the user only has access to site 3.

Comment: You'll want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT cust.siteID)` to eliminate duplicates where different users cannot access the same site.

Comment: @forpas I get no results whether I use `RIGHT JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` i  had it at right join when pasting because I'm experimenting.

Comment: Better edit your question and explain which table is which and also post sample data and expected results.

Comment: Is `listOfSites` a comma-separated list? Then you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672

Comment: @Barmar it is a comma-separated list.. i already parsed the list and created a table from it. The list has 5 sites which are now one site per row in `userSiteAccess`

Comment: So it's NOT a comma-separated list in the table.

Comment: The query you posted is not for a specific user, it's for all users.

Comment: @forpas I added an example of what the table would look like and the expected outcome.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for the confusion, the table has nothing that is comma separated. It is a regular table. I added an small example of what is happening and the expected outcome.

Comment: So you want tho count the sites that a specific user has not access?

Comment: @forpas that's correct. I want to know if the list of sites has any siteIDs that are NOT valid for a specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `RIGHT JOIN`, and you need to specify the user ID in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM userSiteAccess AS usa
LEFT JOIN sitesVsUsers AS cust
    ON usa.listOfSites = cust.siteID AND cust.userId = 2
WHERE cust.siteID IS NULL
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jPzrJdofX8aQyeXamWmmk/0)

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select count(*) counter
from tablea a
where not exists (
  select 1 from tableb
  where userid = 50 and siteaccess = a.listofsites  
)
```