# Remove All Backslash into string in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this type of string

```
'160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\', \'63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc'
```

In one column and I want like

```
'160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77','63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc'
```

This type of result in MySQL

i have to perform query like

```
SELECT * FROM kapp_staging.kols where `kol_id` in (select REPLACE(json_id,'\'',"'") FROM kapp_staging.news_items 
 where `id` = '991'))
```

in where in clause i have subquery and in subquery
i geting

```
'160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\', \'63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc'
```

this type of value
so i need to remove \ from value so my where in query work fine.

i have data like:

```
Kols table
| id | kol_id                                   | name    | data  |
|----|----------------------------------------  |---------| ------|
| 1  |160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77      | balwant | data  |
| 2  |63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc      | vikram  | data  |

news items
| id | json_id | data    |
|----|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------|
| 991  | {'\160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\','\160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\'} | data    |
```

I tried many ways but didn't get this response.

Thanks in Advance : )

Comment: Are you sure the backslashes are really in the string and need to be removed? That looks like the syntax for writing a string that contains quotes, by escaping the embedded quotes.

Comment: yes, beacuse i want to add in where in clause like this

SELECT * FROM kapp_staging.kols where `kol_id` in (REPLACE('160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\',\'63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc','\'',"'"));

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question.

Comment: i update my question can you plz check

Comment: There are no backslashes in the query you're trying to perform.

Comment: Please add sample contents of the `kols` and `news_items` tables and the expected results.

Comment: It shouldn't be `IN REPLACE((select...))` it should be `IN (SELECT REPLACE(...))`

Comment: thanks @Barmar but it's did't work have diffrent idea ?

Comment: I'm getting tired of trying to guess what you're doing. Please add sample data like I asked.

Comment: @Balwant: Please fix this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/9BeLxMcz) to make clear how your data looks like. (and post the new link to the changed fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes aren't in the data, they're just used to escape the quotes when inserting into the table. So you don't need to remove them.

However, you can't use `IN` to match values in a comma-delimited list, you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`; see [Search with comma-separated value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672)

You also need to remove the quotes and curly braces before you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.*
FROM kols AS k
JOIN news_items AS n 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(k.kol_id, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(json_id, '{', ''), '}', ''), "'", ''))
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/xfzuSMX8)

Things would be much easier if you normalized your data and put the list of IDs into a separate table with one row per ID.

Comment: yes, i tries this solutions but i want to do in mysql not in php.

i have to perform this query but \ is in my string so query dose't work

SELECT * FROM kapp_staging.kols where kol_id in (REPLACE('160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\',\'63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc','\'',"'"));

Comment: My first code snippet is MySQL without PHP.

Comment: Do you only want to remove the backslash before `'`? The question says you want to remove all backslashes, that's what my answer does.

Comment: SELECT * FROM kapp_staging.kols where `kol_id` in (REPLACE('160f7a4a-766a-4c23-a155-8bd3f7389f77\',\'63233bfc-b663-4c73-890b-00a48d79c4dc','\\'',''));

but did't work

Comment: There's no backslash in that string, so there's nothing to remove. The backslash is the escape character needed to allow the embedded quote.

Comment: this is not literal i select from another table via sub query.

Comment: Please update the question, show the table contents and the query.

Comment: @Balwant I've updated my answer to show how to do it with your data, and added to your dbfiddle to demonstrate it.