# Mysql - Count + Sum Two Separate Tables Based on Value of Cell in Query

Tags: sql, mysql

Here's a basic table setup with some dummy data. The basic understanding is - service_names is a list of events. Attendance is a list of individual rows that will contain people's info that attended that event. Visitor_attendance is just a single row that has a count in it of a group of people who we don't have info for.

SERVICE_NAMES:

```
ID     Name     service_join
1      Event 1  1,2
2      Event 2  1,2
3      Event 3  3
```

ATTENDANCE:

```
ID      service_name(This will match the ID shown in 'service_names')
10      1
11      1
12      1
13      2
14      2
15      3
16      3
```

VISITOR_ATTENDANCE:

```
ID      service_name(this will match ID in service_names)      visitor_count
21      1                                                      5
22      2                                                      2
22      3                                                      7
```

... so this means, there was 3 events.
Event 1 is joined with event 2.
Event 3 is separate.

What I want to figure out is this:

How do I write a query in MySQL that would return every row and column from service names, but with a couple additional columns:

1. total_attendance that adds together a count of all rows in ATTENDANCE and the value of 'visitor_count' from visitor attendance based on whatever ID's are present in service_join.
2. A count of all rows in attendance where service_name match the current row's ID
3. The value of visitor_count in visitor_attendance where the service_name matches the current row's ID

It's OK if this last column is null if service join is empty.

So for example, my query should say this:

SERVICE_NAMES:

```
ID     Name     service_join  total_attendees  attendance  visitors
1      Event 1  1,2           12               3           5
2      Event 2  1,2           12               2           2
3      Event 3  3             9                2           7
```

I tried Left joins, joins, outer joins, subqueries, and the like. I'm not finding a good combination.

Comment: Why is `service_join` a comma-separated list? Why not just have the ID of the event that this event is joined with?

Comment: [is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: If Event 2 is 1,2 just like Event 1; why isn't the visitors 5 like event 1?

Comment: Service Join is a comma-separated list mainly by design. It's attendance tracking software, but I've coded in the ability to join services together (such as, if an upstairs and a downstairs event is going on). So we can individually view the attendance for each event, but collectively know which events were connected together for master attendance purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE to get the count of rows in `attendance`. Join that with `visitor_attenance` to add that together with the sum of `visitor_count` for each event.

Use `FIND_IN_SET()` to join that with the comma-delimited list in `service_join`. See [Search with comma-separated value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql/16210672#16210672), and use `SUM(total_attendees)` to get the combined total.

Then join that with the other tables to get their individual rows.

```
WITH attendance_count AS (
  SELECT service_name, COUNT(*) AS attendance
  FROM attendance
  GROUP BY service_name
) 
select sn.ID, sn.Name, sn.service_join, SUM(acva.total_attendees) AS total_attendees, a.attendance, va.visitor_count
FROM service_names AS sn
LEFT JOIN attendance_count AS a ON sn.ID = a.service_name
LEFT JOIN visitor_attendance AS va ON va.service_name = sn.ID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ac.service_name, attendance + IFNULL(SUM(visitor_count), 0) AS total_attendees
  FROM attendance_count AS ac
  LEFT JOIN visitor_attendance AS va ON ac.service_name = va.service_name
  GROUP BY ac.service_name
) AS acva ON FIND_IN_SET(acva.service_name, sn.service_join)
GROUP BY sn.ID, sn.Name, sn.service_join, a.attendance, va.visitor_count
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4saY6NS53nZBsRmaVEkzAC/1)

Comment: Verified that this works and solves the problem!

Bonus points because that code looks like absolute witchraft to me but runs fast.

Comment: The important thing to learn is to break it down into manageable subtasks, as with most complex programming tasks. That's where the CTE comes from, since those counts are needed in two places.

Comment: Plus, the main problem I was encountering was that I couldn't use a COUNT inside of a SUM, and I couldn't (in my moderate amount of mysql experience) come up with a way to subquery it well enough that I could do what you did here. This is a handy way of working around that issue. I just read-and-re-read the code a dozen times, and I understand now the process. Thanks again!

Comment: There may also be a way to do it with window functions. I'm not as experienced with them.